# Resize images automatically in CollectionViewCell in CollectionView with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView with horizontal UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

[image: Here is the layout:]

**I am trying to achieve:**

If a device orientation is portrait, UIImageView width will be qual to view.width and let the height be calculated automatically (like it usually happens with Auto Layout). And the same for the landscape mode. *Example - standard photo app on the Iphone.*

Unfortunately i don't see how to achieve it with autoLayout. I set constraints on UIImageView for it to be equal in size to the cell. But looks like the sell itself cannot be pinned to the Parent View.

After reading similar questions looks like cells must be resized programmatically using

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {



return CGSize(width: width, height: height)

}
```

And here i am stuck because i know the width of the screen but don't know how to calculate the height dynamically.

**About image height:**

I have my image declared like this:

```
var pageImages = [UIImage]()

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: ImageDetailViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageDetailViewCell


    let curr = indexPath.row
    let imgName = data[albumNumber][curr]["image"]

    cell.DetailImageView.image = UIImage(named: imgName!)


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the proper `UIImageView` resize setting (say, aspect fit/fill), then you just need to set the cell's height to your collectionView's (you get a pointer to it as one of the `...sizeForItemAtIndexPath...` method parameters) height. You also should call the `- layoutIfNeeded` method on your cell afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` to change the size of collection view cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var numberOfCellInRow : Int = 3
    var padding : Int = 5
    var collectionCellWidth : CGFloat = (self.view.frame.size.width/CGFloat(numberOfCellInRow)) - CGFloat(padding)
    return CGSize(width: collectionCellWidth , height: collectionCellWidth)
}
```

You can get the size of cell via :

```
((UICollectionViewFlowLayout) self.collectionViewName).itemSize.height)
```

You can get the image size via :

```
let sizeOfImage = image.size
let height = image.height
```

If you want to change the height then change it manually by  `return CGSize(width: collectionCellWidth , height: cellheight)`

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I have only one sell and one row. So your code just makes my images square. As i mentioned above my issue is with calculating proper height.

Comment: do you want to get collection view cell height? @alahab

Comment: yes. I need to calculate the height based on the photo aspect ratio and the width of the screen. But that's only my guess. Maybe there are other ways to achieve auto resizing of images like in the standard Photo App and i just don't know about it.

Comment: I added "About image width" section to my original question. As you see my image is declared in cellForItemAtIndexPath function. Could you please advise how can i access its width and height outside of it and in sizeForItemAtIndexPath function in particular. Then i can try to do some simple math with aspect ratio.

Comment: may you get help from `self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexpath)` @alahab

Comment: @alahab Sorry, I didn't quite get what's the problem? If you use the proper `UIImageView` resize setting (say, aspect fit/fill), then you just need to set the cell's height to your `collectionView`'s (you get a pointer to it as one of the `...sizeForItemAtIndexPath...` method parameters) height. You also should call the `- layoutIfNeeded` method on your cell afterwards. Did I get you right?

Comment: @DaniilKorotin That's it! My resize settings were off. Now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot for!

Comment: @DaniilKorotin you can post your answer separately and i will accept it as the right one.

Comment: Added the separate answer.